# How to change different shades of colors to one color only on specific parts of a photo?

Tags: gratis, image-editor, color

I have photos of people that don't have a single background color behind them.

I would need to redo it completely white. But, since the color has a bunch of different shades, I can't simply fill it.

XnView allows you to replace the color even with a certain tolerance. However, there are so many shades in the sample photo (I can't post the original one here) that with a certain tolerance it starts to change color even where I want to keep it.

How can I solve this, please? Or is there another way to do it? I don't care if it is other software, but I want it to be free.

Thank you

PS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What OS/Device? iOS/macOS can do this natively these days, just drag the subject to separate it from the background, or save in a new document. For anything that can't do it yet, just google 'background remove'. There are a myriad free online services.

Comment: Hello @Tetsujin I don't have Apple products. And yes, there may be different online services, but I just need an offline one. And I honestly don't know how I should phrase something like that?

Comment: This type of "AI" [not really AI, it's machine learning] is coming to everything right now. Photoshop can do it offline, I don't know of anything else cross-platform that can at the moment, but just google 'background remover windows' or similar to see what's on offer.